# Angular Change Component Declarations Location

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-module

this might be a dumb question but there it goes:

In my angular project i want to change my components declarations from angular.module.ts to modules/modules.modules.ts.

In order to make my src/app structure look like:

```
src/
   app/
   .  modules/
   .  .  about/...
   .  .  banner/...
   .  .  contact/...
   .  .  portfolio/...
   .  .  services/...
   .  .  testimonial/...
   .  .  modules.module.ts
   .  app-routing.module.ts
   .  app.component.html
   .  app.component.scss
   .  app.component.spec.ts
   .  app.component.ts
   .  app.module.ts
```

In Resume want to move all my component declarations to modules/modules.module.ts

This is my best attemp so far:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// Modules Components
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { TestimonialComponent } from './testimonial/testimonial.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    AboutComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    TestimonialComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    AboutComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    TestimonialComponent,
  ],
})
export class ModulesModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
// Angular CLI
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// App Component
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Pages Components
import { HomePageComponent } from './pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from './pages/about-page/about-page.component';
import { ServicesPageComponent } from './pages/services-page/services-page.component';
import { PortfolioPageComponent } from './pages/portfolio-page/portfolio-page.component';
import { PortfolioSinglePageComponent } from './pages/portfolio-single-page/portfolio-single-page.component';
import { ContactPageComponent } from './pages/contact-page/contact-page.component';

// Modules Components
//import { BannerComponent } from './modules/banner/banner.component';
//import { ServicesComponent } from './modules/services/services.component';
//import { PortfolioComponent } from './modules/portfolio/portfolio.component';
//import { TestimonialComponent } from './modules/testimonial/testimonial.component';
//import { AboutComponent } from './modules/about/about.component';
//import { ContactComponent } from './modules/contact/contact.component';
import { ModulesModule } from './modules/modules.module';

// Angular Material
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';

// Third Party
import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';

// PWA
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';

// Environment
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// Firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    AboutPageComponent,
    ServicesPageComponent,
    ContactPageComponent,
    PortfolioPageComponent,
    PortfolioSinglePageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ModulesModule, // here
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    OwlModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: true, //environment.production,
    }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please note that i just changes the names to simplify the question. And it was fully working when the declarations wore in the app.module.ts

Comment: Hi. Which error message are you receiving ?

Comment: the [error](https://pastebin.com/mj6kKtMf), for me it looks lie angular is trying to compile the page without having all the imports imported, or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `export` each component in `ModulesModule`. This strategy is similar to what is described in [Sharing modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules). Also it looks like the errors you are receiving are unknown element errors surrounding owl carousel, angular router, and possibly other modules. Try creating a `SharedModule` that imports/exports these third party modules as well as any shared components and import it into your other modules where they are used:

Shared:

```
@NgModule({
 imports:      [CommonModule],
 declarations: [],
 exports:      [CommonModule, OwlModule, RouterModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Modules:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
  ],
  exports: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
  ],
})
export class ModulesModule { }
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: yeah, i saw the documentation, but i still unable to perform this change.

My `pages.mudule.ts` is just like that, import all components, then inside NgModule i import `CommonModule`, declare all components, and export then.

Comment: Did you add each of the pages components to `exports` of `PagesModule`?

Comment: I created a working example of this structure as described by the answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2jzux . Declare and export from `PagesModule`, import `PagesModule` in `AppModule`, use components from `PagesModule`

Comment: i changed the code in my question, to match my current code

Comment: @Victor Yeah that structure works in the example I created. What error are you getting?  If you remove the other third party modules, does it make any difference? If still an issue, update the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2jzux) by forking it to create the same structure you have in your application.

Comment: @Victor I updated the answer. Based on the errors it looked like they were entirely around module such as owl carousel and router that were no longer accessible in the `ModulesModule`. The modules imported in `AppModule` cannot simply be used in `ModulesModule`. You need to either import the same third party modules in `ModulesModule` directly or use something like a `SharedModule` to export those modules you need to use across different parts of your application.

Comment: it worked, thank you, i created the `SharedModule`, i imagine that all third_party apps i could import in the `SahredModule` and then import it anywhere i need, even in the app.module.ts

Comment: i would suggest you to add `Based on the errors it looked like they were entirely around module such as owl carousel and router that were no longer accessible in the ModulesModule. The modules imported in AppModule cannot simply be used in ModulesModule. You need to either import the same third party modules in ModulesModule directly or use something like a SharedModule to export those modules you need to use across different parts of your application.` to your answer, so i can mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error you need to:

- Import RouterModule in your ModulesModule
- Import OwlModule in your ModulesModule

Since I am old and my eyesight is not the best I might have missed some :)